# When i run 'pip install scipy' on my Pycharm Terminal i get Attribute Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

i am trying to install scipy package on one of my Pycharm projects. i get the following Attribute Error,
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'text_temp'

following is the exception that i am getting,

```
Collecting scipy
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 179, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 315, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 131, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 294, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 242, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 269, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 196, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_internal/index.py", line 639, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_internal/index.py", line 614, in find_all_candidates
    self._package_versions(page.iter_links(), search)
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_internal/index.py", line 775, in _package_versions
    for link in self._sort_links(links):
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_internal/index.py", line 759, in _sort_links
    for link in links:
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_internal/index.py", line 971, in iter_links
    namespaceHTMLElements=False,
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_vendor/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 47, in parse
    return p.parse(doc, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_vendor/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 289, in parse
    self._parse(stream, False, None, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_vendor/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 134, in _parse
    self.mainLoop()
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_vendor/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 239, in mainLoop
    new_token = phase.processSpaceCharacters(new_token)
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_vendor/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 469, in processSpaceCharacters
    self.tree.insertText(token["data"])
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_vendor/html5lib/treebuilders/base.py", line 357, in insertText
    parent.insertText(data)
  File "/Users/rohitgite/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_vendor/html5lib/treebuilders/etree.py", line 109, in insertText
    if not self._element.text_temp:
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'text_temp'
```